# Why does linking my program with iso_c_binding cause undefined references to __gfortran_?

Tags: c++, c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have an legacy Fortran code that I want to mix with a new C/C++ program.

The Fortran subroutine allocates dynamically some arrays that I want to pass to c program. I will only get the size of these arrays after running the Fortran code.

After getting some tips here in this forum I arrived to the following code that I thought it would best compile, link and run.

Actually I can compile my C code and my Fortran code separately, but it doesn't link giving the following errors:

```
undefined reference to _gfortran_runtime_error

undefined reference to _gfortran_os_error
```

I'm using g++ and GFortran compilers version 5.4.0, and linking both .o files with g++ and the option -lg fortran.

fortran code:

```
subroutine test_allocation(outp) bind(c)
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    type (c_ptr), value :: outp
    integer, target ::b(2)
    integer(c_int), pointer :: a(:)
    b(1)=1
    b(2)=2
    allocate(a(2))
    a=>b
    call c_f_pointer(outp, a,[2])
end subroutine
```

c code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
extern "C" void test_allocation(int ** ptr);
int main ()
{
        int* ptr;
        test_allocation(&ptr);
}
```

EDIT:

As Vladimir F said on comments there was a mistake in my compiler option. The correct is -lgfortran.

Now it's linking but the results is not what I expect. I change a little my code to show this:

Fortran code:

```
subroutine test_allocation(outp) bind(c)
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    type (c_ptr), value :: outp
    integer, target ::b(2)
    integer(c_int), pointer :: a(:)
    b(1)=1
    b(2)=2
    allocate(a(2))
    a=>b
    print*, "a(1) in Fortran: ", a(1)
    print*, "a(2) in Fortran: ", a(2)
    call c_f_pointer(outp, a,[2])
    print*, "outp after c_f_pointer: ",  outp
end subroutine
```

C code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" void test_allocation(int** ptr);



int main ()
{
        int* ptr;
        test_allocation(&ptr);
        cout<<"ptr[0] in C: "<< ptr[0]<<endl;
        cout<<"ptr[1] in C: "<< ptr[1]<<endl;

}
```

The output is:

```
a(1) in fortran:            1
a(2) in fortran:            2
outp after c_f_pointer:       140726088663920
ptr[0] in C: 1447122753
ptr[1] in C: 1107265857
```

I also tried changing the declaration of extern function to the following and it still does not work:

```
extern "C" void test_allocation(int*& ptr);
... 
test_allocation(ptr);
```

The output is:

```
a(1) in fortran:            1
a(2) in fortran:            2
outp after c_f_pointer:       140729541703872
ptr[0] in C: 1447122753
ptr[1] in C: 1107265857
```

Comment: I don't know why you have the error, but the code is incorrect, you cannot pass the pointer by `value`. Please show us your complete commands and the complete error output. Do not just select two lines. You can take the welcome [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You write `-lg fortran` with a space. Is that a typo? Is that a typo just here or also in your linking? Please show the **complete** commands and outputs.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I changed to `-lgfortran` and it linked. Thanks. But it is still not giving me correct results as you can see in mey answer.

Comment: Yes, I already wrote in my very first sentence that your code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works. Instead of using `C_F_POINTER` I used the function `C_LOC`.

I also removed the parameter `VALUE` from the `TYPE(C_PTR)` declaration.

Here is the code:

```
subroutine test_allocation(outp) bind(c)
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    type (c_ptr)    :: outp
    integer  ::b(2)
    integer,dimension(:), pointer :: a
    b(1)=1
    b(2)=2
    allocate(a(2))
    a=b
    print*, "a(1) in fortran: ", a(1)
    print*, "a(2) in fortran: ", a(2)
    outp=c_loc(a)
    print*, "outp after c_loc: ",  outp
end subroutine
```

and it's output:

```
a(1) in fortran:            1
a(2) in fortran:            2
outp after c_loc:              36866928
ptr[0] in C: 1
ptr[1] in C: 2
```

The following link helped me a lot although I'm not using intel compiler:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/269660

Comment: For my purposes it does. I just want to use this subroutine as an interface  to have a copy of `a` in the C side (`ptr`). But you made me curious. What should I do so that `a` could be used in the C side?

Comment: A is a ponter so its target should remain valid.

Comment: You didn't have to search in Intels sites of just read my first comment... It is all there.